# iOS GameKit Can't Connect via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, gamekit

I'm trying to connect between 2 devices, iOS Simulator and iPhone device.

```
_picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
_picker.delegate = self;
_picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
```

For some reason the devices can discover each other only via wifi.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator does NOT work with bluetooth, try with 2 devices, should work ..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [CoreBluetooth](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) framework instead ?

There is support in the Similator also for CoreBluetooth (by attaching an external Bluetooth LE USB dongle).

As @David says Gamekit's Bluetooth is probably not supported by the simulator.